# Pass value from command to another without writing to disk

Tags: shell, pipe, stdin

I want to pass the output of one command into another without writing to disk, but the second command is interactive so passing the value into `STDIN` will prevent the second command from being allocated a `pty` (because of this the second command only accepts loading that value from a file by design).

What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to the following:

```
generic-vault --decrypt "my-secret" | interactive-command --file /proc/self/fd/0
```

Is there any way to do this whilst preventing any other processes run by the same user won't be able to view the output of the first process?

Comment: Would a ram disk fulfill your requirement of not writing to disk?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming bash (or something similar):

```
interactive-command --file <(generic-vault --decrypt "my-secret")
```

[Process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Answer (score -1):

Using pipes (and bash), you could do something like:

```
mkfifo mypipe

while sleep 1
do
    generic-vault --decrypt "my-secret" > mypipe
done
```

And then access the information via:

```
read data < mypipe
interactive-command --file $data
```